# certain table sizes are increasing continuously in mirth server i.e. installed on amazon Linux

Tags: mysql, datatables, mirth

We are using mirth connect server in which we are using mysql.D_MC1.ibd, D_M1.ibd D_MM1.ibd these are the tables of which size is increasing continuously,
because of that I have stopped mcservice for now. I have truncated these tables and again the size is increasing.

I have stopped mcservice for now. I have truncated these tables and again the size is increasing.